# Cauchy Riemann and Differentiability

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, proof-verification

Consider the following proposition.

> **Proposition** Let the function  $$ f( z ) := u(x,y) + iv(x,y) $$ where $ z = x+iy $ be defined throughout in a $ \eta $-neighbourhood of $ c = a + ib $.  Suppose that the first order partial derivatives of the functions $ u $ and $ v $ with respect to $ x $ and $ y $ exist everywhere in $ \eta$-neighbourhood, are continuous at $ (a,b) $ and satisfy 
>   $$ u_{x} = v_{y}   \quad   u_{y}  = - v_{x}  $$ at $(a,b) $, then the function $ f $ is complex-differentiable at $ z_{0} $.

I tried the following proof, but apparently, I am not using the full power of the continuity of the partial derivatives at $ (a,b) $. Can anyone see if the proof is okay?

*Proof* : Let $ l  = h + ik    \neq 0 $ be such that $ l   +  c  $ is contained in the $ \eta $-neighbourhood. We have 
$$ D = \left | \frac{f(c+l) - f(c)}{ l }   - ( u_{x}(a,b) + iv_{x}(a,b)  ) \right  |   =    $$ $$   \frac{  | u ( a + h , b + k ) - u(a,b) - hu_{x}(a,b)  - ku_{y}(a,b) + i( v ( a + h , b + k ) - v(a,b) - hv_{x}(a,b)  - kv_{y}(a,b) |  } {   \sqrt{ h^{2} + k^{2}} }  \leq  $$
$$ \frac{  | u ( a + h , b + k ) - u(a,b) - hu_{x}(a,b)   - ku_{y}(a,b) |  +  | v ( a + h , b + k ) - v(a,b) - hv_{x}(a,b)  - kv_{y}(a,b)  |} {  \sqrt{ h^{2} + k^{2}} } $$
Let 
$ A  = | u ( a + h , b + k ) - u(a,b) - hu_{x}(a,b)   - ku_{y}(a,b)  | $, 
$ A_{1} = | u(a+h, b+k) - u(a,b+k) -  h u_{x}( a, b+k) | $, 
$ A_{2} =  |  u(a , b+k ) - u(a,b) - k u_{y} ( a,b) | $, 
$ A_{3} =   |  hu_{x} ( a, b+k)  -  h u_{x} ( a,b) | $,
$ B = | v ( a + h , b + k ) - v(a,b) - hv_{x}(a,b)  - kv_{y}(a,b)  |  $, 
$B_{1} = | v(a+h, b+k) - v(a,b+k) -  h v_{x}( a, b+k) |$,
$B_{2} = |  v(a , b+k ) - v(a,b) - k v_{y} ( a,b) | $, 
$B_{3} =  | h  v_{x} ( a, b+k)  -  h v_{x} ( a,b)  |           $.

1. Triangle inequality implies that $ A  \leq A_{1} +  A_{2} +  A_{3 }  $ and $ B \leq  B_{1}  + B_{2}  + B_{3}  $. 
   Let $ \epsilon > 0 $.
2. Existence of partial derivative $ u_{x} $ at $ (a,b+k) $ implies that  there exists a $ \delta_{1} > 0 $ such that $ | h |  <  \delta_{1}  \implies A_{1} <  \frac{ \epsilon}{8} |h|  $.
3. Existence of partial derivative  $ u_{y }$ at $ (a,b) $ imply that there exist $ \delta_{2} > 0 $ such that $ |k|   < \delta_{2}  \implies  A_{2}    <   \frac{ \epsilon}{4} | k | $.
4. Continuity of partial derivative $ u_{x} $ at $ ( a, b ) $ implies that there exist  $ \delta _{3} > 0 $ such that $ |k| < \delta_{3}  \implies   A_{3}  <   \frac{ \epsilon}{ 8} |h|  $ .
5. Existence of partial derivative $ v_{x} $ at $ (a, b+ k ) $ implies that  there exists a $ \delta_{4} > 0 $ such that $ | h |  <  \delta_{4}  \implies  B_{1}  <  \frac{ \epsilon}{8} |h|  $.
6. Existence of partial derivative  $   v_{y }$ at $ (a,b )  $  imply that there exist $ \delta_{5} > 0 $ such that $ |k|   < \delta_{5}  \implies  B_{2}    <   \frac{ \epsilon}{4} | k | $.
7. Continuity of partial derivative $ v_{x} $ at $ ( a, b ) $ implies that there exist  $ \delta _{6} > 0 $ such that $ |k| < \delta_{6}  \implies   B_{3}  <   \frac{ \epsilon}{ 8} |h|  $ .

So, whenever $ |h| <   \zeta_{1} =  \min \left  \{ \eta,  \delta_{1} , \delta_{4} \right \} $ and $ |k|  < \zeta_{2} =  \min  \left \{  \eta , \delta_{2} , \delta_{3}  ,   \delta  _ { 5} , \delta _{ 6}  \right \} $, we have $ D \leq  \frac{ A + B}  {  \sqrt{ h ^{2} + k ^ { 2} }  }  < \frac{ 1 } {  \sqrt{ h ^{ 2} + k ^{ 2} } }   \left (  \frac{ \epsilon}{8} |h| +   \frac{ \epsilon}{4} | k | +  \frac{ \epsilon}{ 8} |h| +  \frac{ \epsilon}{8} |h| +  
 \frac{ \epsilon}{4} | k | +  \frac{ \epsilon}{ 8} |h| \right ) 
 = \frac{  \epsilon } { 2  \sqrt{ h ^{ 2} + k ^{ 2} } }   ( |h| +  |k| ) <   \epsilon $, which implies that whenever $ |c| <  \zeta =  \min \left \{   \zeta_{1} , \zeta_{2}  \right \} $, we have $ D < \epsilon $.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for not reading everything but it seems to me that are not aware of the following fact:

> **Proposition.** Let $U$ be an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $f : U \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function whose first order partial derivatives (with respect to each variable) exist everywhere in $U$ and are continuous at some point $a \in U$. Then $f$ is differentiable at $a$.

In other words, the fact that $f$ is differentiable at $z_0$ in your problem has nothing to do with the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Comment: I know this fact, of course. When I said that the function was differentiable, I meant complex differentiable! I was trying to prove it, but wasn't able to use the fact that all four derivatives are continuous at a given point. Anyways, I figured out the mistake, so no worries. :)